# Index performance, clustered vs non clustered

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization, indexing

If a table only needs 1 index, it seems like clustered is generally the way to go.  It is faster because it does not have to reference back to the data via a key, and it also doesn't take disk space the way a non clustered index does.

My question is with multiple indexes, is it better to remove clustered index all together?  The logic behind this is that if you have non clustered indexes WITH a clustered index, they don't directly refer back to the actual data rows anymore, but to the clustered index instead.  So it seems like there would be a significant performance hit by using the clustered index as a proxy.  It seems like the best thing to do would be to not use clustered indexes at all if you think you will need more than 1 index on the table.

Comment: Which database are you using?  MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: sql server.    15char

Comment: well yes, i would agree.  if you only need 1 index, it should be a clustered.  but for analytical purposes, it is common for tables to have many indexes, so (n-1) will have to be non clustered.  and if there is a clustered index, and a non clustered index scan occurs, instead of the non clustered results being RID's, it is a reference to the clustered index.  so my question is if there are multiple indexes on a table, is it better to just leave out the clustered index so that the searches don't have to go through the clustered index every time a non clustered search happens-it should save time

Comment: Check out covering indexes. Thus is not directly answer you question but a covering index contains additional fields and can provide information without reading rows from the table. At a storage penalty of course.

Comment: @faester covered indexes is an exception to my question... they are still very useful though.  if the index covers the query, then there is no need to use RID (or refer back to the clustered index if one exists), so it would be an exception to my question.

Comment: The performance hit from using a logical rid rather than a physical rid [is maybe less than you assume](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15048/3690). Plus if you store the base table as a heap it means no index at all can use it without needing to perform lookups back to it (quickly gets expensive) or duplicating the data in the NCI itself. Meaning it is stored twice and needs to be maintained twice.

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for.  my only complaint is that i wish FILIP tested other statements.. like 'where', 'grouping', etc.  I don't see myself using insert, update, delete too much on the table in question, but it's still interesting stuff to see.. I tend to load the data in bulk, and just drop the index before hand to make it faster.  then i just re-add the index after.  but still, 20-30% is pretty significant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table has a proper clustered index there is no benefit to removing it.
If you have several indexes then pick the best candidate for clustered.
Typically it is your PK.
When you create a PK by default it clustered.
PK is your best candidate for clustered unless you have specific reason not to use it.

I don't follow your assertion.

> "If you have non clustered indexes WITH a clustered index, they don't
>   refer back to the actual data rows anymore, but to the clustered index
>   instead. So it seems like there would be a significant performance
>   hit."

If the clustered index is in the data then referring to the clustered index is referring to the data.  The data is physically organized by the clustered index.  Where is the significant performance hit?

[Clustered Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms190639%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

> With few exceptions, every table should have a clustered index defined

If one of those few exception was another index then it would be called out.
Another non-clustered index is not a reason to not have a clustered index.

[Nonclustered Index Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms177484%28v=sql.110%29)

The row locators in nonclustered index rows are either a pointer to a row or are a clustered index key for a row, as described in the following:

- If the table is a heap, which means it does not have a clustered
  index, the row locator is a pointer to the row. The pointer is built
  from the file identifier (ID), page number, and number of the row on
  the page. The whole pointer is known as a Row ID (RID).
- If the table has a clustered index, or the index is on an indexed
  view, the row locator is the clustered index key for the row. If the
  clustered index is not a unique index, SQL Server makes any duplicate
  keys unique by adding an internally generated value called a
  uniqueifier. This four-byte value is not visible to users. It is only
  added when required to make the clustered key unique for use in
  nonclustered indexes. SQL Server retrieves the data row by searching
  the clustered index using the clustered index key stored in the leaf
  row of the nonclustered index.

They had the option use a RID even if there was a PK.  Why do you think clustered index is slower?

Comment: @ the last paragraph- clustered should always be faster than non clustered because clustered doesn't have to refer back to the data.  But i was under the impression that if there is already a clustered,  non clustered results have to run through the entire clustered index B-tree in order to get to the corresponding row number. Does that make sense?  so instead of just referencing a row number directly like it usually would, to get the row number it has to run through the clustered AFTER the non clustered.  This is where a performance hit comes from..

Comment: @user3739391 Not I am not getting that.  If a RID was faster they would have used it.  What evidence you you have that a RID is faster?  Do you know the structure of a RID (in SQL)?  Multiple indexes is common.  If not having a clustered index was better in a multiple index scenario you would find that recommendation big and bold.

Comment: in theory, it should be faster.  clustered is faster than non clustered for that reason- it doesn't have to use the RID.  but for a non clustered (that isn't a covered index), the results of that then have to be run through the clustered index to find the correct record, because RID isn't used when there is also a clustered on the table.  So as a result, it is logical to conclude that this will mean a performance hit.

Comment: You have NO evidence a RID is faster so stop asserting that in theory it is.  SQL had the option to use RID and did not.  You find no recommendation in MDSN that supports your in theory assertion.

Comment: ok, i will test it when i get back to work and get back to you.  and RID is NOT always faster, but in the case of a clustered index already existing on the table it *should* be, because it can just use the RID to identify the record instead of having to run through the entire clustered index to find the record.  it's just logical.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/performance-of-non-clustered-indexes-on-heaps-vs-clustered-indexes/15048#15048     .  Turns out it actually does increase performance 20-30%, just like i thought.

Comment: @user3739391 I am not dropping my clustered indexes but this has been fun.

Comment: @user3739391  it might happen that when you are removing clustered index optimizer choosing a better execution plan, but certainly rid(Extra 8 bytes) is not a good option to use, use a narrow clusted index insted, if you want to go into details why without clustered index why it is performing better please post execution plan , with and without clustered index.

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma here is a research study that shows the 20-30% performance increase.  I didn't test this myself.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/performance-of-non-clustered-indexes-on-heaps-vs-clustered-indexes/15048#15048

Comment: i just did a quick test(sql server 2012) just for selects
when lookup required. Time is almost same , but logical reads are almost half in rid lookup then key lookup